# Dynamic block columnview and column width

Tags: org-mode

I collect propoerties of my titles in a columnview dynamic block. But it seems to ignore the width settings from the #+COLUMNS:

Example :

```
#+COLUMNS: %20ITEM(Projet) %10lead(Meneur)

#+BEGIN: columnview :maxlevel 2 :id global :maxlevel 2
#+END
```

The Project columns is very large and i'd like to shrink it.
Putting a <20> inside of the dynamic table will not survice a block update.

Any idea ?

Comment: I've hit the same issue - I've tried various ways of shrinking columns produced by the columnview dynamic block and none seem to work.  Looking at v9.3 org-dblock-write:columnview function it doesn't seem to acknowledge any width character.  I can see earlier versions of the function had this - ":width    enforce same column widths with <N> specifier". The behaviour is specific to the dynamic block - when using the column view mode or exporting it is straightforward to control width, but this does feel like a bit of a feature gap.  Did you ever find a solution or raise on the org mailing list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:format` option to set the columns:

```
#+BEGIN: columnview :format "%20ITEM(Projet) %10lead(Meneur)" :maxlevel 2 :id global :maxlevel 2
#+END
```

Comment: Great tip, thanks. I can format each columnview in a document as I want. I tested it and it works, ... except for the size of the columns, putting %20 or %5 won't change anything.

Comment: Agreed this is another way of specifying the columns, but the widths are still ignored in the dynamic block, and the result is identical to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```lisp
(advice-add 'org-dblock-write:columnview :around
            (defun org-dblock-write:columnview--around
                (orig-fun &rest orig-args)
              (pcase-let*
                  ((`(,params)
                    orig-args))
                (apply orig-fun orig-args)
                (org-table-shrink))))

;; (advice-remove 'org-dblock-write:columnview 'org-dblock-write:columnview--around)
```

[image: Shrink columns in colview tables]

```
#+STARTUP: shrink

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(advice-add 'org-dblock-write:columnview :around
            (defun org-dblock-write:columnview--around
                (orig-fun &rest orig-args)
              (pcase-let*
                  ((`(,params)
                    orig-args))
                (apply orig-fun orig-args)
                (org-table-shrink))))

;; (advice-remove 'org-dblock-write:columnview 'org-dblock-write:columnview--around)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

* Nulla do minim cupidatat mollit sunt laboris
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: test
:END:

** Aliquip adipiscing sed irure
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LOREM: Et quis dolore aliqua non cillum eu ut nulla id proident, laborum fugiat minim ad magna anim in consequat et
   :END:

** Pariatur commodo non do sunt
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LOREM: Pariatur quis velit ipsum exercitation culpa occaecat nulla.
   :END:

** Ad ut ea cillum quis
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LOREM: Culpa fugiat reprehenderit magna aliquip eiusmod mollit elit
   :END:

** Nulla eiusmod exercitation sit
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LOREM: Esse proident, officia ullamco magna id eiusmod commodo qui nulla ad consectetur nisi eiusmod ad eiusmod nostrud ad ut
   :END:

** <25>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LOREM:    <50>
   :END:

#+BEGIN: columnview :id test :format "%10ITEM %15Lorem(LOREM)"
| ITEM                                         | LOREM                                                                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Nulla do minim cupidatat mollit sunt laboris |                                                                                                                        |
| Aliquip adipiscing sed irure                 | Et quis dolore aliqua non cillum eu ut nulla id proident, laborum fugiat minim ad magna anim in consequat et           |
| Pariatur commodo non do sunt                 | Pariatur quis velit ipsum exercitation culpa occaecat nulla.                                                           |
| Ad ut ea cillum quis                         | Culpa fugiat reprehenderit magna aliquip eiusmod mollit elit                                                           |
| Nulla eiusmod exercitation sit               | Esse proident, officia ullamco magna id eiusmod commodo qui nulla ad consectetur nisi eiusmod ad eiusmod nostrud ad ut |
| <25>                                         | <50>                                                                                                                   |
#+END:
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `org-table-shrink` doesn't check on `org-columns-*` variables which is where the width you set in columnview `:format` and `#+columns:` would go.

However it does check `<N>` in the field, so a patch could be modify the `org-dblock-write:columnview` function to add a row of `<N>` somewhere. As the funciton actually produce a 2d list of the table to insert first, it's as simple as adding `(setq table (append table '("<20>" "<15>" "" "<10>")))` between the making of `table` and the insertion of the dynamic block.

Here's my slightly modified version using doomemacs's `after!` macro to ensure that it overides the default one.

```
(after! org
  (defun hermanhel/org-dblock-write:columnview (params)
  "Write the column view table.

PARAMS is a property list of parameters:

`:id' (mandatory)

    The ID property of the entry where the columns view should be
    built.  When the symbol `local', call locally.  When `global'
    call column view with the cursor at the beginning of the
    buffer (usually this means that the whole buffer switches to
    column view).  When \"file:path/to/file.org\", invoke column
    view at the start of that file.  Otherwise, the ID is located
    using `org-id-find'.

`:exclude-tags'

    List of tags to exclude from column view table.

`:format'

    When non-nil, specify the column view format to use.

`:hlines'

    When non-nil, insert a hline before each item.  When
    a number, insert a hline before each level inferior or equal
    to that number.

`:indent'

    When non-nil, indent each ITEM field according to its level.

`:match'

    When set to a string, use this as a tags/property match filter.

`:maxlevel'

    When set to a number, don't capture headlines below this level.

`:skip-empty-rows'

    When non-nil, skip rows where all specifiers other than ITEM
    are empty.

`:vlines'

    When non-nil, make each column a column group to enforce
    vertical lines.

`:width'

    When non-nil, add a row of <N> at the bottom. N is the widths set in the   
    format.
"
  (let ((table
     (let ((id (plist-get params :id))
           view-file view-pos)
       (pcase id
         (`global nil)
         ((or `local `nil) (setq view-pos (point)))
         ((and (let id-string (format "%s" id))
           (guard (string-match "^file:\\(.*\\)" id-string)))
          (setq view-file (match-string-no-properties 1 id-string))
          (unless (file-exists-p view-file)
        (user-error "No such file: %S" id-string)))
         ((and (let idpos (org-find-entry-with-id id)) (guard idpos))
          (setq view-pos idpos))
         ((let `(,filename . ,position) (org-id-find id))
          (setq view-file filename)
          (setq view-pos position))
         (_ (user-error "Cannot find entry with :ID: %s" id)))
       (with-current-buffer (if view-file (get-file-buffer view-file)
                  (current-buffer))
         (org-with-wide-buffer
          (when view-pos (goto-char view-pos))
          (org-columns--capture-view (plist-get params :maxlevel)
                     (plist-get params :match)
                     (plist-get params :skip-empty-rows)
                     (plist-get params :exclude-tags)
                     (plist-get params :format)
                     view-pos))))))
    (when table
      ;; Prune level information from the table.  Also normalize
      ;; headings: remove stars, add indentation entities, if
      ;; required, and possibly precede some of them with a horizontal
      ;; rule.
      (let ((item-index
         (let ((p (assoc "ITEM" org-columns-current-fmt-compiled)))
           (and p (cl-position p
                   org-columns-current-fmt-compiled
                   :test #'equal))))
        (hlines (plist-get params :hlines))
        (indent (plist-get params :indent))
        new-table)
    ;; Copy header and first rule.
    (push (pop table) new-table)
    (push (pop table) new-table)
    (dolist (row table (setq table (nreverse new-table)))
      (let ((level (car row)))
        (when (and (not (eq (car new-table) 'hline))
               (or (eq hlines t)
               (and (numberp hlines) (<= level hlines))))
          (push 'hline new-table))
        (when item-index
          (let ((item (org-columns--clean-item (nth item-index (cdr row)))))
        (setf (nth item-index (cdr row))
              (if (and indent (> level 1))
              (concat "\\_" (make-string (* 2 (1- level)) ?\s) item)
            item))))
        (push (cdr row) new-table))))
      (when (plist-get params :vlines)
    (setq table
          (let ((size (length org-columns-current-fmt-compiled)))
        (append (mapcar (lambda (x) (if (eq 'hline x) x (cons "" x)))
                table)
            (list (cons
                               "/"
                               ;; (make-list size "<>")
                               (reverse (cl-reduce (lambda (result newelt) (cons (format "<%s>" (nth 2 newelt)) result)) org-columns-current-fmt-compiled :initial-value '() ))
                               ))
                        ))))
      ;; add a line of <N> at bottom to convert columnsview column widths to org-table wolumn widths
      (when (and (not (plist-get params :vlines)) (plist-get params :width) )(setq table (append table
              (list 
               ;; (make-list size "<>")
               (reverse (cl-reduce (lambda (result newelt) (cons (format "<%s>" (nth 2 newelt)) result)) org-columns-current-fmt-compiled :initial-value '() ))
                          ))))
      (let ((content-lines (org-split-string (plist-get params :content) "\n"))
        recalc)
    ;; Insert affiliated keywords before the table.
    (when content-lines
      (while (string-match-p "\\`[ \t]*#\\+" (car content-lines))
        (insert (pop content-lines) "\n")))
    (save-excursion
      ;; Insert table at point.
      (insert
       (mapconcat (lambda (row)
            (if (eq row 'hline) "|-|"
              (format "|%s|" (mapconcat #'identity row "|"))))
              table
              "\n"))
      ;; Insert TBLFM lines following table.
      (let ((case-fold-search t))
        (dolist (line content-lines)
          (when (string-match-p "\\`[ \t]*#\\+TBLFM:" line)
        (insert "\n" line)
        (unless recalc (setq recalc t))))))
    (when recalc (org-table-recalculate 'all t))
    (org-table-align)
        (org-table-shrink)))))

  (defun org-dblock-write:columnview (params)
      (hermanhel/org-dblock-write:columnview params)
                )
  )
```

I didn't check the earlier versions of the function, but I guess this method is what the old version Phil mentioned have used.